# are arguments required to build pslib code?

Tags: c

I have pslib installed and in the latest version on an ubuntu system.
the library is installed at: "/usr/include/libps/pslib.h"
when I try compiling, the postscript PS objects are not recognized.

```
...
/usr/bin/ld: draw.c:(.text+0x1868): undefined reference to `PS_stroke'
...
```

and so on. I don't see any thing on the pslib webpage, about needing to include the library in the gcc build command.

what do I need to do to build C code with pslib? I am on Ubuntu Linux

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <libps/pslib-mp.h>

void * my_malloc(PSDoc *p, size_t size, const char *caller) {
    void *a;
    a = (void *) malloc(size);
//  printf("Allocating %d bytes at 0x%X (%s)\n", size, a, caller);
    return(a);
}   

void * my_realloc(PSDoc *p, void *mem, size_t size, const char *caller) {
    return((void *) realloc(mem, size));
} 
  
void my_free(PSDoc *p, void *mem) {
//  printf("Freeing memory at 0x%X\n", mem);
    free(mem);
}


int main() {
    PSDoc *psdoc;
    int antiqua;
    float boxwidth, boxheight, baseline, colsep, leftmargin;
    float fontsize;
    int boxed;

    boxwidth = 100;
    boxheight = 630;
    baseline = 100;
    colsep = 20;
    leftmargin = 100;
    boxed = 0;
    fontsize = 10.0;

    PS_boot();
    psdoc = PS_new2(NULL, my_malloc, my_realloc, my_free, NULL);
    PS_open_file(psdoc, "polish.ps");
    PS_set_info(psdoc, "Creator", __FILE__);
    PS_set_info(psdoc, "Author", "Uwe Steinmann");
    PS_set_info(psdoc, "Title", "Polish letters");
    PS_set_info(psdoc, "Keywords", "polish, latin2, iso-8859-1");
    PS_set_info(psdoc, "BoundingBox", "0 0 596 842");

    PS_set_parameter(psdoc, "inputencoding", "ISO-8859-2");
    PS_set_parameter(psdoc, "warning", "true");

    antiqua = PS_findfont(psdoc, "plr10", "", 1);

    PS_begin_page(psdoc, 596, 842);

    PS_setfont(psdoc, antiqua, 10.0);
    PS_set_value(psdoc, "leading", 15.0);
    PS_show_xy(psdoc, "±æê³ñó¶¼¿ ¡ÆÊ£ÑÓ¦¬¯", leftmargin, 100);
    PS_show_xy(psdoc, "><=!abc~_-", leftmargin, 200);

    PS_end_page(psdoc);
    PS_deletefont(psdoc, antiqua);
    PS_close(psdoc);
    PS_delete(psdoc);
    PS_shutdown();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Any library other than `libc` needs to be specified explicitly when linking. You need `-lpslib`

Comment: `pslib.h` is not the library, it's a header file with the function declarations.

Comment: that did it. how would I know what to call that library? I tried -lpslib as a guess, but that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-lps` when linking (or maybe `-lps-mp`).

This is specified in the [documentation](http://pslib.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?manpage=pslib):

> Programs which want to use pslib will have to include the header file `libps/pslib.h` and link against `libps`

The general rule is that `-lXXX` is used to link the library names `libXXX`.